# C++: vector initialisation in constructor

Tags: c++

in this code i am unable to understand how vecor is initialised?

```
class Student :  public Person{
private:
    vector<int> testScores;  
public:

    Student(string firstname,string lastname,int id,vector<int> scores):Person(firstname,lastname,id)
    {
            this->testScores=scores;
    }       
    char calculate()
    {
        int sum=0;
        char result;
        for(int i=0;i<testScores.size();i++)
        {
            sum+=testScores[i];  
        }
        int res=sum/testScores.size();
        if(res<=100 && res>=90)
        {
            result='O';   
        }
        else if(res<90 && res>=80)
        {
            result='E';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how vecor is initialised?

It's default initialized implicitly (i.e. initialized by the default constructor). To be complete, it's default initialized at first, and then copy assigned in the body of constructor.

The more effiient way is using [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
class Student : public Person {
private:
    vector<int> testScores;  
public:
    Student(string firstname, string lastname, int id, const vector<int>& scores)
      :Person(firstname, lastname, id), testScores(scores)
    {
    }  
    ...
};
```

It's copy initialized now (i.e. initialized by the copy constructor).

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `Student`, the `std::vector<int> testScores` is initialised via the assignment operator (copy-assignment in this case) using the contents of the `scores` parameter passed to the `Student` constructor.

As an aside, it's better to pass `scores` (and the `std::string` args) by const reference to the constructor of `Student` to avoid unnecessary copying:

```
Student(const std::string& firstname, const std::string& lastname, const std::vector<int>& scores) 
    : Person(firstname, lastname) {
    testScores = scores; // uses copy-assignment to initialise testScores
}
```